# in app purchase detail in database: I am using V3 API for in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using V3 API for in app purchase. Transaction is fine. I have used webservice to store transaction detail. But its not getting inserted into the DB. So even after the transaction, the user detail remain unchanged which is a big issue now.
Can any one help me????

Comment: is your payment transaction state complete.?

Comment: Transaction is working affecting the credit card and amount. But no  data after that.